# How to filter an array of object by comparing its id with the values of a different array

Tags: angular

I have an array of object 'compareJson' using this I am displaying a list in html. I have an array 'Cars', using which I need to compare its value(1,4..) with 'id' attribute of 'compareJson' and needs to display the same list in HTML on click 'duplicate' button. If there is same id in multiple objects ,those all objects should display

### app.component.html

```
<button (click)="duplicate()" >Get values </button>
<div *ngFor="let item of  compareJson">Item listed - {{item.details}}</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  compareJson = [
    {
      id: '1',
      details: 'Photography details'
    },
    {
      id: '1',
      details: 'Writing details'
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      details: 'Painting Details'
    }
  ];

  Cars = [1, 4];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get the objects from `compareJson` where the `id` attribute exists in the `Cars` array?

You could filter `compareJson` with values in the `Cars` array like this:

`const matches = compareJson.filter((object) => Cars.includes(object.id));`.

With your example `matches` would equal `[{ id: '1', details: 'Photography details'}]`